# PHP regex replace a word in url path

Tags: php, regex, url

Im trying to replace a word in a url path.

F.e. `host.com/path/to/find` should become `host.com/path/to/count`.

But im obviously not getting this to work.

I tried to get this group: `(?:/count|/find)?` at the end of the string

and all in front of it to replace it with `$1/count`.

But always when i try the get the part before the `(?:/count|/find)?` -part i mess it up.

Here is a test:

EDIT: **all keys represent the test (srouce) url. And all values represent the expected result.**

So if there is no "/count" on the path then it should be added.

If there is a "/count" at the end then there is nothing to do.

If there is a "/find" at the end of the path then it should change to "/count".

If there is the workd "count" *somewhere* in the url (like "countleaveMeAlone") it should (ofc) not be changed.

```
$urls = [

    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to'                => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/'               => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find'           => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find/'          => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find?some=foo'  => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count?some=foo',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find/?foo=some' => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/?foo=some',

    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count'           => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/'          => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count?some=foo'  => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count?some=foo',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/?foo=some' => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/?foo=some',

    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/toleaveMeAlone'                 => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/toleaveMeAlone',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/leaveMeAlone'                => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/leaveMeAlone',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/countleaveMeAlone'           => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/countleaveMeAlone',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/leaveMeAlone'          => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/leaveMeAlone',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/countleaveMeAlone?some=foo'  => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/countleaveMeAlone?some=foo',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/leaveMeAlone?foo=some' => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/leaveMeAlone?foo=some',
];

$format = "%-70s%-70s%s\r\n";
echo sprintf($format, 'TEST', 'EXPECT', 'SUCCESS');
foreach ($urls as $url => $expect) {
    $tmp = explode('?', $url);
    $url = rtrim($tmp[0], '/');
    $query = isset($tmp[1])
        ? $tmp[1]
        : '';

    /**
     * Pattern
     * /
     *      \A                  --start string
     *      (.*)                --get all before
     *      (?:/count|/find)?   --get optional "/find" or "/count"
     *      \z                  --end string
     * /
     */
    $url = preg_replace(
        "#\A(.*)(?:/count|/find)?\z#",
        '$1/count',
        $url
    );

    $url .= strlen($query)
        ? '?' . $query
        : '';

    echo sprintf($format, $url, $expect, var_export($url === $expect, true));
}
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: So you want to replace 'find' with 'count' in a URL pretty much? Wanna clarify before I put in my answer.

Comment: Can "find" appear multiple times in the url or just once in the path?

Comment: $url = preg_replace(
        "#\A(.*)(?:/count|/find)?\z#",
        '$1/count',
        $url
    ); Replace this with
$url = preg_replace(
        "#\A(.*)(?:/count|/find)?\z#",
        "$1/count",
        $url
    );

Comment: Why not use str_replace? If it's just a static replace we are talking about

Comment: You are right @Andreas, str_replace can also be used, and if you need `preg_split`, `$url = preg_replace('/\/find/', '/count');`

Comment: How come you expect two different outputs for 1 and the same string - `http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count` => `http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count` AND `http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/`?

Comment: Damn you guys are fast here :) 
Yes i want to replace "/find" with "/count".
Yes "find" (no slash) could appear in url or host (who knows in future).
EDIT:
It also could happen that none of both are present.
So at the end  - what ever the url is - the count should be present at the end.

Comment: See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497265/php-regex-replace-a-word-in-url-path#comment75987942_44497265). Why 2 different outputs are expected for 1 and the same string? What do you mean by "the end of the string"?  The end of the path before the query string? Please *revise* the test cases.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew All test urls (keys) are uique. The expected may become the same (depends on slash at the end of source or not).
The end of the string is end of the path. I already cut the query by explode.

Comment: If they are unique, `"~\A(.*?)(?:/count|/find)?\z~"` would work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Looks almost good. But pls try my test script. You will see it does change the urls that it should not. _It also removes trailing slash but thats not a problem at all._

Comment: Perhaps `"~(/to)(?:/?$|/find\b)~"` ? Don't see why those that already have 'count' would have to be matched.

Comment: @cotton you can have a look at my answer, and let me know if that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
$urls = [
'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to'                => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count',
'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/'               => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count',
'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find'           => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count',
'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find/'          => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/',
'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find?some=foo'  => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count?some=foo',
'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find/?foo=some' => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/?foo=some'];
foreach ($urls as $url => $expect) {   
$new_url = str_replace("find","count",$url);
echo $new_url."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Does not work. F.e. the 1st `http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to` does not change to `http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count`

Comment: Just i replace find to count. Please explain your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern: ([Pattern/Replacement Demo with Official Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/4BYYLs/1))

```
~^([^?]+?)/?((?:(?:/count|leaveMeAlone)(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|(?:find/??)?)((?:(?<=find)/)?)((?:\?.*)?)$~
```

Layman's Breakdown:

- `~` Starting pattern delimiter (not a slash, so slashes don't need to be escaped in the pattern)
- `^` Match the start of the string
- `([^?]+?)` Capture one or more characters that are not a question mark (lazy/non-greedy)
- `/?` Match zero or one slash
- `(` Capture...

  - `(?:(?:/count|leaveMeAlone)(*SKIP)(*FAIL))` Disqualify entire string if `/count` or `leaveMeAlone` is found before `?`
  - `|` Or
  - `(?:find/??)?` Optionally capture find with zero or one trailing slash (lazy)
- `)` ...end capture
- `((?:(?<=find)/)?)` Capture zero or one slash IF it is preceded by `find`
- `((?:\?.*)?)` Capture the optional query string portion of the url
- `$` Match the end of the string
- `~` Ending pattern delimiter

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0bc2d2f09611dfad7102f2def14e60e32ef43648))

```
$urls = [
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to'                => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/'               => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find'           => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find/'          => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find?some=foo'  => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count?some=foo',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find/?foo=some' => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/?foo=some',

    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count'           => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/'          => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count?some=foo'  => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count?some=foo',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/?foo=some' => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/?foo=some',

    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/toleaveMeAlone'                 => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/toleaveMeAlone',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/leaveMeAlone'                => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/leaveMeAlone',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/countleaveMeAlone'           => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/countleaveMeAlone',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/leaveMeAlone'          => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/leaveMeAlone',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/countleaveMeAlone?some=foo'  => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/countleaveMeAlone?some=foo',
    'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/leaveMeAlone?foo=some' => 'http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/leaveMeAlone?foo=some',
];

$pattern='~^([^?]+?)/?((?:(?:/count|leaveMeAlone)(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|(?:find/??)?)((?:(?<=find)/)?)((?:\?.*)?)$~';
$replace='$1/count$3$4';
foreach($urls as $url=>$expected){
    echo "$url\n";                                   // your input
    echo preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$url),"\n";  // my output
    echo "$expected\n\n";                            // your expected output
}
```

Output:

```
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count

http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count

http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count

http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find/
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/

http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find?some=foo
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count?some=foo
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count?some=foo

http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/find/?foo=some
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/?foo=some
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/?foo=some

http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count

http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/

http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count?some=foo
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count?some=foo
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count?some=foo

http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/?foo=some
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/?foo=some
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/?foo=some

http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/toleaveMeAlone
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/toleaveMeAlone
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/toleaveMeAlone

http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/leaveMeAlone
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/leaveMeAlone
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/leaveMeAlone

http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/countleaveMeAlone
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/countleaveMeAlone
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/countleaveMeAlone

http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/leaveMeAlone
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/leaveMeAlone
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/leaveMeAlone

http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/countleaveMeAlone?some=foo
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/countleaveMeAlone?some=foo
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/countleaveMeAlone?some=foo

http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/leaveMeAlone?foo=some
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/leaveMeAlone?foo=some
http://foo-bar.host.com/entity/to/count/leaveMeAlone?foo=some
```